# Не работает Wi-Fi на ноутбуке с Linux Ubuntu. Как подключить?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Сегодня первый раз поставил Linux. Версия Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (с официального сайта). Но, к сожалению, не работает wi-fi модуль. Модель ноута Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro 15 2019. Когда прогружаюсь в Windows, то wi-fi работает отлично, то есть проблема где-то в софте. Подключить ноутбук к интернету через кабель тоже не могу, у него нет Ethernet интерфейса. Как подключить wi-fi? В Linux абсолютный нуб, а работать как-то надо.

Comment: На уровне виртуальной машины пытались смотреть этот вопрос?

Comment: Вывод `lspci -nk -v` и `lsusb -t` покажите.

Answer (score 0):

Настройка сети - не самое простое в люнихе, а wi-fi тем более. Поэтому рекомендую Вам воспользоваться подходящим инструментом - *NetworkManager*. На самом деле это целая совокупность инструментов разного уровня и предназначения. Например, *nmcli* - это вариант для командной строки, *nmtui* - вариант с псевдографикой. И (самое главное) есть *NetworkManager* демон, который постоянно сидит в памяти и следит за состоянием сети.

Если на Вашем ноуте эта утилита не установлена, настоятельно рекомендую установить её. Скорее всего, все Ваши проблемы тут же и исчезнут.

Если же он установлена, то надо найти на таск-баре иконку этого демона (две жирные стрелки навстречу друг другу - вверх и вниз) и щёлкнуть правой мышкой по иконке. Там будет пункт меню "Изменить соединения".  Заходите в него.

Дальнейшее зависит от того, что Вы там увидите...